# AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport appending on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-domain

I am currently trying to have a user fill a form out on my personal website. After they fill it out, I want them to submit it and pre populate a form on a third party website that I do not have control over. When submitting, I notice if the user hasnt been to the third party site it appends

```
AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
```

to the url. I want to get rid of that because when it appends it, it does not populate the form as intended. IS this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well I did not find my answer but a work around, I created an invisible iFrame to grab the cookies from the other site so when the form is submitted, that does not get appended.